# Installing a cross-compiled linux kernel on Pine64(or Raspberry Pi or any other similar Single Board Computer)

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, cross-compilation

I am preparing a new linux kernel for Pine64, because it is slow, I did the cross-compilation on a linux PC.

I am looking for a way to run `make install && make install modules` without copying the whole ~3GB of source and object files of the compiled kernel over to the Pine64 just to install the compiled binaries.

Is there a way to either create some "installation package" or just omit the unneeded files (`*.o`, `*.c`, ...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the modules to an alternate path:

```
mkdir /tmp/pine64
make modules_install INSTALL_MOD_PATH=/tmp/pine64
```

Then you can copy the modules from `/tmp/pine64`, and the `bzImage` kernel image, to your Pine64.

Another approach is to build a binary package:

```
make binrpm-pkg
```

or

```
make bindeb-pkg
```

depending on your target distribution. This will produce a package containing the kernel and modules.

Comment: You can always compile a kernel. Booting it successfully in a Arm board is a very different conversation. ;-P

Comment: @Rui my Pine64 runs the mainline kernel.

Comment: I am actualy just trying to run a different configuration of my running kernel(https://github.com/longsleep/linux-pine64/releases    3.10.105-0-pine64) so it "should" be relatively painless. Thx, this seems to be what I am looking for.